# The text won't go vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to get the text to go vertically centered like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UreMt.png but it doesn't seem to want to align.

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
h4 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row .row {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
  height: 250px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.innertext {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="innertext">Text Test Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r0gsewtd/1/

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0gsewtd/2/)

```
.innertext {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[class*="col-"] {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
    height: 250px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Add last 2 lines to your `[class*="col-"]`

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Also you can check this :
[How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can vertically center the text by applying table display property
add

```
 display:table;
```

to parent class, div-col-md-4 
then add

```
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
```

to     .innertext

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r0gsewtd/3/)

Then the code becomes

```
 .col-md-4 {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
background-color: #eee;
background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
height: 250px;
display:table;
}

.innertext {
display:inline-block;
width:90%;
    display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;

}
```